# Bit Manipulation and XOR

Tags: c++, algorithm, xor, bitmask

I have an Question regarding bit manipulation in Algorithms.

Given an array of integers, every element in array appears thrice except for one element which occurs only once. Find that element which appear only once.

Example:

```
Input : [1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1]  
Output : 4
```

I came across solution using `XOR` but I am not able to understand it. Below is solution:

```
int singleNumber(vector<int> A) {
    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;
    for(auto n:A){
        first = (first ^ n) & ~second;
        second = (second ^ n) & ~first;
    }
    return first;
}
```

Can someone explain how below 2 lines of code works?

```
first = (first ^ n) & ~second;
second = (second ^ n) & ~first;
```

***[Edited]***

I had included `cout<<first<<" "<<second<<endl;` for every iteration in loop but it is showing following output which I am not able to understand. How this lead to solution?

```
1 0
3 0
7 0
4 3
4 0
6 0
4 2
5 0
4 1
4 0
```

Comment: At what point in the execution are you confused?  Show your printed trace, or the desk-checking you've done; explain where you're stuck.

Comment: @Prune Hi, I had edited my question now please answer it.

Comment: I'll wait for the trace and explanation I requested.

Comment: @Prune I am not stuck in execution. I am stuck in only explanation, why this code works? So, how I am suppose to answer explanation part?

Comment: Look at *all* the values in the loop, and the results of each operation.  Explain to us just where you don't follow the sequence.  Perhaps work through a little algebra to derive the new values of `first` and `second` as a function of `n`.  Work through an 8-row truth table to see what happens with each combination of inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this code does is count the occurrences of each bit, in parallel, mod 3.

The nth bit of `first` and the nth bit of `second` together make this counter.

Watch what happens when I write a bit of `first` and `second` together and then incorporate a bit from the new number.  Here are all the possibilities:

```
             secondfirst    00  01  10    00  01  10
                 new bit     0   0   0     1   1   1
first=first^new &~second     0   1   0     1   0   0
+ sec=sec^new & ~first      00  01  10    01  10  00
```

As you can see, the two bits are left unchanged when the corresponding bit in the new number is 0.  When the new bit is 1, though, they go through a cycle, returning back to `00` every 3 steps.  If the number of 1s is 3n+1, we're left with a 1 bit in `first`